# ngMessages displaying dynamic error for input number as per max or min attributes

Tags: angularjs, html, validation, max, ng-messages

I have been trying for a while to find out information on how to use angular validation to display messages but with the specific min or max attribute.

If I have an `input[type="number"]` field with attributes like `min=1` or `max=10` and the user enters `11` I want a validation message that says: `"The number should be less than 10"`. But the number `10` should be taken from the `max` attribute dynamically.

I'd like to have the messages in a separate template. 
I have the following:

```
<!-- default ng-messages -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="common-messages">
    <span ng-message="required" class="help-block">This field is required</span>
    <span ng-message="maxlength" class="help-block">Must be no longer than {{maxlength}} characters</span>
    <span ng-message="min" class="help-block">This number must be greater than {{min}}.</span>
    <span ng-message="max" class="help-block">This number must be less than {{max}}.</span>
    <span ng-message="number" class="help-block">A number is required</span>
    <span ng-message="date" class="help-block">A date is required</span>
</script>
```

and then in a form

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="app.packaging.PackagingAddController as package">
    <form name="packageForm" ng-submit="package.save()" role="form" novalidate class="form-horizontal">
        <input type="text" name="packageCount" ng-model="package.model.packageCount" class="form-control" max="10 " />
        <div ng-messages="packageForm.packageCount.$error" role="alert" ng-show="packageForm.$submitted || packageForm.packageCount.$touched" ng-messages-multiple>
              <div ng-messages-include="common-messages"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The problem is that the error shown is `This number must be less than .` so the {{max}} is not being injected. Is there any way to achieve this so that I can reuse the common-messages template?

PS: This thread [How to get min and max values of input angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114170/how-to-get-min-and-max-values-of-input-angularjs) is not useful for my question since it does not reuse a template nor it reads from the html input max attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do it simply calling in your view like this `{{max}}`, you have to create a custom directive to achieve what you want.

Comment: That was just an example of what I am trying to achieve. Are you saying ngMessages does not support anything similar out of the box? Thanks